# android 4.2.2 keyboard changes horizontal scroll

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My problem is (after a lot of search and many tests) that my application works fine with devices with android 4.0 and 4.1, .

But with an emulator with Android 4.2.2, every time that I use the keyboard (appears, disappears, touching a key) my HorizontalScrollView scrolls to the right end of the view.

Somebody knows the problem and has a solution?